# Why is this mySQL database not connecting to Netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql, database, macos, netbeans

The mysql database will not connect to the netbeans code. I am using a Mac Device and have installed mySQL on my device (it is running fine on localhost:8080). However, the connection through Java is not working. I believe there may be an error in the following line "conn = Driver Manager..." since it is not executing. I am unsure of how to change the password / what the password is.

- Restarting Xampp

[Screenshot of connection code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TUr2.png)

Expected result: user input is sent to mySQL database
Actual result (error): seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEdAY.png)

Comment: What version of netbeans are you using and can you connect to it using the Databases tab in services?

Comment: In general it would be better if you copy and paste your code/errors in your post rather than attaching images.

Comment: DB_URL + USER , what is this ? Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general database connectivity code .

```
     try
         {
      Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
     Connection con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DatabaseName","MysqlUsername","MysqlPassword");

        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        String query = "YourMysqlQuery";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
```

// You also have to add  'jdbc driver' in lib folder of your project.
If want us to solve the problem in your code then please provide the actual code you have done , Not the image .

Comment: Maybe you could explain a little bit on __how JDBC connections are setup__  regularly in Java (steps & input). Especially since the OP seems either Java-newbie or looking for others solving his homework quickly for him (regarding the lazy formatting of his question and the lack of an [mcve]).